# Linkedin full name search results

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

I've build an app that connects with LinkedIn and allows me to search users. It uses the linkedin api with aouth.

Some parameters you can use are: first-name / last-name / keywords
To search for a person you could for example use first and last name

If you don't no where to split a (foreign) name LinkedIn suggests to use the full name with the keywords parameter (see https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api).

### Example

```
A name like Zubair Ali:

keywords: Zubair Ali or Zubair+Ali or Zubair%20Ali
has no results

first-name: Zubair
last-name: Ali
has more then 100 results
```

I know Zubair Ali is easy to split but it's just an example i know that gives no results and i want to use a full name search so that i can use names from a full name database that also contain names like Wang Chin Hu and Peter van der Veen. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be related to a known issue that is currently under investigation:

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/people-search-not-returning-proper-results

Comment: i found that article as well but i thought it was another issue, i saw your reply on my post at linkedin, thank you